# Postfix with no more space

Tags: postfix

My mails do not arrives anymore, my logs are full of `warning: 545DDC0ECA: write queue file: No space left on device`

But it is a new server (several days), and disks are not full:

```
rootfs            20G   19G  203M  99% /
/dev/root         20G   19G  203M  99% /
devtmpfs          32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            6,3G  336K  6,3G   1% /run
tmpfs            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             13G     0   13G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md2         255G  8,0G  234G   4% /data
/dev/md0         1,8T  454G  1,3T  26% /home
```

What's wrong here please?
Thanks

EDIT:

My fstab file:

```
/dev/md1    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro,relatime,discard  0   1
/dev/md2    /data   ext4    defaults,relatime   0   2
/dev/sda3   none    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb3   none    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/md0    /home   ext4    defaults,relatime,discard   0   2
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
```

Comment: Is something mounted as read-only perhaps? Type dmesg to see if there are system errors.

Comment: No, can't see any errors... But I notice something: in df command I can't see the dir /var... Is it normal?

Comment: Your `/` is full and you don't have a `/var` partition so it's in `/`.

Comment: How can I manage that please? I'm not so advanced to manipulate partitions... :-( I think I have to change the file fstab? What line do I have to add please?

Comment: My fstab: `/dev/md1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro,relatime,discard 0 1
/dev/md2 /data ext4 defaults,relatime 0 2
/dev/sda3 none swap defaults 0 0
/dev/sdb3 none swap defaults 0 0
/dev/md0 /home ext4 defaults,relatime,discard 0 2
proc  /proc proc defaults  0 0
sysfs  /sys sysfs defaults  0 0
tmpfs  /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
devpts  /dev/pts devpts defaults 0 0`

Edited my question to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

Your `/var/spool` is located in your root FS since you haven't created a separate partition for it. You could easily link your `/var/spool/postfix` to a directory on your `/data` or `/home` partitions, considering you have plenty of space there.

Comment: Ok, How can I do that (sorry, newby here...)?
But I need to link all /var because I have other progs here that will have same problem... How to affect whole /var to the 1.5To disk?

Comment: You can create a directory on the other disk, like `mkdir /data/var` or `mkdir /home/var/` and moving the contents of `/var/` there. Then you can remove `/var/` and link it with `ln -s /data/var /var`. You may have to stop a bunch of services if they have open files in `/var`

Comment: One more tidbit: If there are mails in the Postfix queue and you move the queue to another filesystem, it's always a good idea to run `postsuper -s` before you start Postfix again - and not only once, but until the queue ids (which are linked to inode numbers) stop changing.

Comment: Mmmh... I'd like to affect a new partition to /var, it is more clean...

Comment: Then you have to repartition your disks.